# Sequlize ORM :getting Invalid date in postgres after create

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert a string into tables that having the sequlize data type is `DATE`

```
await Image.create(
        {
          path: actualPath,
          image_name: name,
          camera_name: cameraName,
          image_created_time: createdTime,
        },
        { transaction }
      )
```

a sample value of `image_created_time` field is   `2021-11-24 17.31.35`.

After insertion, I m getting the `Invalid date` is for the field `image_created_time`

Not sure how to resolve this issue,

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Indicate date-time values in ISO 8601 and that does the trick:
   `2021-11-24 17:31:35`
2. Check inserted values directly in DB using pgAdmin or DBeaver